# Why am I getting an error when I runspider?

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I am currently working through an exercise where I put Amazon Reviews for a specific product into a csv file. I have put together my code to extract the data but I am getting a syntax error when I go to runspider to put into the csv. This part I copied directly from the practice module I am looking at so I wasn't quite sure what the issue could be. All of the resources I have found on runspider indicate that the code should be correct but clearly I've done something wrong here.

Here is my code. I am getting an error on the very last line:

```
import scrapy

# Implementing Spider
class ReviewspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    # Name of Spider
    name = 'reviewspider'

    allowed_domains = ["amazon.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/B07N49F51N/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewpnt_lft?pageNumber=']


    def parse(self, response):
        names = response.xpath('//span[@class="a-profile-name"]/text()').extract()
        reviewTitles = response.xpath('//a[@data-hook="review-title"]/span/text()').extract()
        starRatings = response.xpath('//span[@class="a-icon-alt"]/text()').extract()
        reviews = response.xpath('//span[@data-hook="review-body"]/span/text()').extract()
        noOfComments = response.xpath('//span[@class="a-size-base"]/text()').extract()
        for (name, title, rating, review, comments) in zip(names, reviewTitles, starRatings, reviews, noOfComments):
            yield {'Name': name, 'Title': title, 'Rating': rating, 'Review': review, 'No of Comments': comments }

scrapy runspider spiders/reviewspider.py -t csv -o - > amazonreviews.csv
```

Here is the Error Message:

```
  File "<ipython-input-35-6e8796e727d9>", line 22
    scrapy runspider <reviewspider.py> -t csv -o - > amazonreviews.csv
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I missing here? I am very new to Python, webscraping and scrapy so any and all breakdown/insight is useful.

Comment: The row that is throwing the error [isn't supposed to be in the file](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#runspider). Could you try to remove the row and try to use it in the shell instead to see if that solves the problem?

Comment: @HampusLarsson The next question I am going to ask is may make me seem really dumb but we all start somewhere. What do you mean by "use it in the shell"? I am operating on google colab. I tried running the line in a fresh code box if that's what you mean. When I do that, I still get that same syntax error code.

Comment: The `scrapy runspider` command is a command-line (often referred to as a 'shell') tool that can launch a scrapy script without needing to first create a project-structure. You could see it as when you execute "ping" from the command-line. I am not familiar enough with google colab to know if you can "execute" shell commands that way. Your best bet - I think - would be to install Python on your device and running the code there.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
scrapy runspider spiders/reviewspider.py -t csv -o - > amazonreviews.csv
```

is not part of your code. It is just command how to run your spider.

Go to your project location via cmd or anaconda prompt. And try

```
scrapy runspider reviewspider.py -t csv -o amazonreviews.csv
```